# Python creating an array from hex bytes

Tags: python, arrays, string, hex

I have the following string:

```
"0c a8 f0 d6 02 00 00 00 00 d0 1c d1 10 d2 00 d3 00 d7 01 d4 78 20 ff"
```

As you can see, it contains hex values and I want to transform it into an array of bytes, using Python **2.4.4** (NOT 3.x, so I don't have the useful `bytearray`). The only way to achieve it as per my knowledge is something like:

```
i = []
i.append(0x0c)
i.append(0xa8)
i.append(0xf0) # ... and so on
.....
z = ''.join(chr(c) for c in i)
```

But this is horrible. Any good hint how to solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'0c a8 f0 d6 02 00 00 00 00 d0 1c d1 10 d2 00 d3 00 d7 01 d4 78 20 ff'.replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decode string replacing all whitespaces

```
s = "0c a8 f0 d6 02 00 00 00 00 d0 1c d1 10 d2 00 d3 00 d7 01 d4 78 20 ff"
x = s.replace(" ", "").decode('hex')
```

or You can use generator statement for example

```
x = ''.join(chr(int(i, 16)) for i in  s.split())
```